# Plotting data having different dimensions using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to plot a simple plot using satellite data. This data contain lat, lon and sla (sea level anomaly). The data I used for this example is located [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4q34D9jmmNIWUQ3UWppTURxZW8/view?usp=sharing) This the simple script I am trying to started experiment with is here:-

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import print_function
import os
import platform
import numpy as np
from netCDF4 import Dataset
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap

width = 10
height = 8

nc_f = ('ctoh.sla.ref.RA2.medsea.0543.nc')
nc_fid = Dataset(nc_f, 'r')
lons = nc_fid.variables['lon'][:]
lats = nc_fid.variables['lat'][:]
sla = nc_fid.variables['sla'][:]

lon_0 = lons.mean()
lot_0 = lats.mean()
lon_max = nc_fid.variables['lon'].lon_max
lon_min = nc_fid.variables['lon'].lon_min
lat_min = nc_fid.variables['lat'].lat_min
lat_max = nc_fid.variables['lat'].lat_max

m = Basemap(projection='merc', lat_0=lot_0, lon_0=lon_0,
            resolution = 'l', llcrnrlon=lon_min, llcrnrlat=lat_min,
            urcrnrlon=lon_max, urcrnrlat=lat_max)
m.drawcoastlines()
m.drawcountries(linewidth=1.0)
# lons,lats= np.meshgrid(lons, lats)
x, y = m(lons, lats)
# plt.figure(figsize=(width, height), frameon=False)
# plt.contourf(x, y, sla)
print(y.shape)
print(x.shape)
print(sla.shape)
cs = m.contourf(x, y, sla)
plt.contourf(np.reshape(x, sla.shape), np.reshape(y, sla.shape), sla)
plt.show()
```

What is the problem I am facing is that the lat and lon contain a shape of 164 and the actual variable to be plotted on basemap contain a shape of (164, 83). Here is the complete error message I have got in terminal:-

```
(164,)
(164,)
(164, 83)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "satellite.py", line 39, in <module>
    cs = m.contourf(x, y, sla)
  File "/home/sundar/.anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mpl_toolkits/basemap/__init__.py", line 521, in with_transform
    return plotfunc(self,x,y,data,*args,**kwargs)
  File "/home/sundar/.anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mpl_toolkits/basemap/__init__.py", line 3644, in contourf
    xx = x[x.shape[0]/2,:]
IndexError: too many indices for array
```

This is the first time I am dealing with data having diffent dimensions/ shapes. How do these data having different shapes are plotted?

Comment: I'm a bit confused, what exactly are you trying to plot? If I understand correctly, you have 164 lat/lon pairs and 83 data points at each pair? How are those 83 points supposed to be interpreted?

Comment: Actually, looking at this example might help from the [docs](http://basemaptutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/plotting_data.html#contourf). Might be worth examining the example data source (which seems to require having `osgeo` library installed). I would also consider changing the question name from `matplotlib` to `basemap` because I've found it to be a whole other beast from `matplotlib`.

Comment: You don't. It's clearly stated in the docstring: `*X* and *Y* must both be 2-D with the same shape as *Z*, or they
must both be 1-D such that ``len(X)`` is the number of columns in
*Z* and ``len(Y)`` is the number of rows in *Z*.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the documentation of [`Basemap.contourf`](http://basemaptutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/plotting_data.html#contourf) correctly, you need to use the `tri` keyword argument for unstructured data:

```
cs = m.contourf(lon, lat, sla, tri=True)
```

or possibly

```
cs = m.contourf(x,y, sla, tri=True)
```

depending on what your data is.

Comment: I don't know who down voted my question. If they have not understood, they should have asked for the clarification. You gave me the correct answer. Thank you for pointing out the mistake.

Comment: I would guess that the 3 people who voted your question down were unable to see the real problem which is kind of hidden behind a bunch of code which is not directly a [MCVE]. Also at first sight reading the question it may seem that you are asking about how to plot data with different shapes using matplotlibs `contourf`, which is of course not possible, and one may also expect someone to find that out without asking a question. Placing the fact that you are using `Basemap.contourf` which is different from matplotlibs `contourf` might have prevented that.